# Eager loading of some of the navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an MSSQL storedproc, which I'm executing via EF4 through the context. This results an `IEnumerable<T>`, which returns and deserializes all the result from the SP.

The problem is, that I want to do eager loading on some of the navigation properties.

Calling `.AsQueryable().Include("Navigation_Property_Path").ToArray()` does not help.

Is there any way to eager load navigation properties of entities already in the context?

I don't really want to alter my SP, to return IDs of my entities (basically int array), and then execute select on the EF.Context using the ID for WHERE, and then using the Include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because SP invocation is not composable at the SQL level. EF does not support eager loading for that.

Maybe you can switch from an SP to an inline TVF?

Comment: Could you please elaborate the "inline TableValuedFunction" option? Also isn't it possible to eager-load navigation properties for entities already in the context/result?

Comment: @Csabi you can import a TVF into EF and use it in a query as if it was a table. That enables you to compose a more complex query including includes.; YOu can eager-load navigation properties but that is a different mechanism. It would work in your case but not as efficiently (a select n+1).

Comment: Funny thing my SP calls a TVF, so I can use the TVF... IF I upgrade to EF5, which I'm not sure whether I can jump right now :/

Anyway, thx for the reply, I mark as answer.